# c# (3.5) use TableAdapters to read/write null DateTime values to a database

Tags: c#, database, nullable, tableadapter

I am connecting to a database using VS2008 DataSets. One of the Tables within the database contains a DateTime Column that allows nulls (i.e. Type: DateTime?)

MSDN [Datasets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172138.aspx) categorically states:

> The Nullable or Nullable structure is not currently supported in the DataSet.

However on the MSDN site for [TableAdapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx) states that TableAdaters CAN support Nullable Types:

> The TableAdapters support nullable types Nullable(Of T) and T?. For more information on nullable types ... For more information on nullable types in C#, see Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide).

I'm confused!

In the DataSet Designer I have set the offending Column's property to 'AllowDBNull=True' but whenever I run a TableAdapter Query that returns a null DateTime (SELECT * FROM UDF) I get the following Exception: *"ArguementOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime."*

One idea I had was to change the type of the Column to System.Object to correctly handle the null values and then I can do the conversions in my own code, however, I still get the same exception being raised.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638746/table-is-nullable-datetime-but-dataset-throws-an-exception) suggests how to deal with the nulls once the query has returned, however I can't get the query to return.

How can I modify the TableAdapter and/or Dataset to allow me to run a query on the Table that can deal with the nulls in the database?

Comment: Better show the query. It ought to just work.

Comment: I think the query works, I imagine the issue is with the auto-generated TableAdapter/Dataset that cant interoperate the null DateTime and just raises an exception.

Comment: No, generated datatables can handle nullable columns just fine.

Comment: Yes ... sorry, I should have clarified that when adding the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use the TO_CHAR() Oracle function and tell the Table Adapter to expect a string value

```
SELECT to_char(NULL_DATE_FIELD,'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') FROM *
```

This means that there is some conversion that needs to happen in the using code. Not ideal though!