# How to set null value in column of data table of type Integer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having one integer column in a data table and I want to set null value in that column. I have done AllowDBNull true but still it doesn't work if a null value is getting added.

Following are the configuration which I have done for Column

[image]

I am getting following exception
[image]

Can anyone help mi for this?

Comment: Please, provide textual representation of error. Some of use can't see images.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign DBNull to a field in the DataTable. When you allow DBNull in a `DataTable`, an extra method is generated. In this case: `SetParentApplicationRoleIdNull()`

*for example:*

```
var newRow = DataSet.ChildApplications.NewChildApplicationRow();
newRow.AField = "Some text";
newRow.SetParentApplicationRoleIdNull();
DataSet.ChildApplications.AddChildApplicationRow(newRow);
```

---

This is also while checking the value. You can't directly use the 'property' `ParentApplicationRoleId`, If you want to read it, you'll have the check it first with another generated method: `IsParentApplicationRoleIdNull()`

*for example:*

```
foreach(var row in DataSet.ChildApplications.Rows)
{
    if(!row.IsParentApplicationRoleIdNull())
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"ParentApplicationRoleId: {row.ParentApplicationRoleId}");
    }
    else
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("ParentApplicationRoleId: is DBNull, and can't be shown");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try set DataType as Sytem.Int32? May it have to be nullable.

Could you pls check this answer [Table is nullable DateTime, but DataSet throws an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638746/table-is-nullable-datetime-but-dataset-throws-an-exception)

Answer (score 0):

The "?" behind a datatype makes it nullable.

Example:

```
int? t = null;
```

So nzrytmn is right!

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the `NullValue` property of the data column to something that is not "`(ThrowException)`"

Answer (score -2):

Please declare that value as nullable int(int?). then it will accet all null values