# Strongly typed dataset not generating Nullable<> type args in Add<tablename>Row method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, strongly-typed-dataset

I've used DataSets for a long time, gotten to know them inside out, even to the extent that I've no problem editing the XML directly to overcome limitations of the designer when working some less-than-mainstream databases but I'm looking for a sense check on something here..

I'm nearly certain that in the past, when I've set a column datatype to be a primitive type like `Int32`, `DateTime`, `Guid` *and also* have declared `AllowDbNull=true`, that the code generated by the msdatasetgenerator has produced an `Add<tablename>Row()` that has had `int?` / `DateTime?` / `Guid?` in the arguments, so that null can be passed and internally, the dataset uses DBNull.Value etc when writing to the database etc

I've just generated a few datasets in the designer for VS2017 pro, and none of the primitive columns that are `AllowDBNull=true`, have a nullable argument in the `Add<tablename>Row()`

I don't have any old projects to had to double check at the moment; does anyone know if anything has changed with recent versions of the dataset generator that have knocked out the nullable arguments facility on the  `Add<tablename>Row` method?

Edit: Here, [Table is nullable DateTime, but DataSet throws an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638746/table-is-nullable-datetime-but-dataset-throws-an-exception) Rob Rossney seems to be confirming what I thought was the case when he says:

> Is particularly bad because typed data sets do use nullable types in some places - for instance, the AddRow() method for the table containing the nullable DateTime column described above will take a DateTime? parameter.

(Answers of *"no, you're actually going crazy, AddRow() has never had nullables.. You're thinking of the other method BlahBlah()"* are fine.. Even just *"it has never supported this, you're going crazy"* is also fine. Hopefully the actual answer is *"you've forgotten to also set the `ABC` property on the DataColumn; it's that that makes the generator generate nullable arguments, not `AllowDbNull=true`"*

Note that I'm *not* asking about setting the type of a DataColumn to be e.g Nullable - I know this cannot be done; but I'm convinced that for declared nullable primitive columns the generated code used to be helpful in some places, allowing a null to be passed and wrangling with it in the designer generated code.." )

Comment: As a minor update, I note that the tableadapter direct methods like `Insert` acquire a nullable type argument for primitive columns declared as allow null, even though the `Add<x>Row` appears not to have a nullable type. Perhaps the answer is *you/Ross are thinking of the tableadapter methods for directly inserting rows to the db, not the add<x>row convenience method for adding a new row to the datatable*